# How to install Linux with the same apps available on another computer?

Tags: linux, installation, clone

I have my Linux laptop configured in the best possible way, with the right settings and installed applications.

Can I extract a text file that summarises what is installed, and pass it to another computer so that it can be a pseudo-clone?

I do not want an exact clone, but just the same applications updated to their latest release.

It would be nice if such a thing could be done across different operating systems (e.g. HURD, BSD, OSX, ...).

Technically it should not be hard. I should parse the original hard disk, creating a list of all the executables. And then have an installer that could read such a file, and install what best matches the list contents.

Comment: You don't mention which distro you use.  Mint includes a utility (MintBackup) that does exactly that.

Comment: @fixer1234 - That's because I am not looking for a specific distro, but for a general tool (actually I am using Debian and Devuan). MintBackup seems to be a classic backup utility.